# Hiding part of html coding on mobile devices

Tags: html, menu

this is my first question, so I apologize if I do something wrong.

I'm designing a website for a friend of mine's catering business, and I've created a simple menu using an unordered list.

For mobiles devices and tablets, I've added the following code to make the pages scale down.

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

The problem is, the menu doesn't scale down and is off the screen. To combat this, I've created a menu using the following code which I wish to use on mobile devices.

```
<select> 
<option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>     
<option value="index.html">Home</option> 
<option value="about.html">About us</option> 
<option value="/blogs/five-simple-steps-blog">Blog</option> 
<option value="/pages/about-us">About Us</option> 
<option value="/pages/support">Support</option> 
</select> 

<script>
$("select").change(function() {
window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
</script>
```

Now, I wish to hide the original  using css when a mobile device is used, and then hide the  when a desktop is used. To do this, I've used the following CSS.

```
select
{
display:none;
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
ul    { display: none; }
select { display: inline-block; }
}
```

Except, for some reason, when using an iphone to browse the website, both the ordinary website and the  are shown. Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Depends on which model you're targeting, your media query value for max-width is too high. See here: http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPhone

Comment: Okay, so I've adjusted the max-width to 320px, but the problem still persists, when browsing on a mobile device, the "display: none;" isn't applied to the ordinary menu...

Answer (score 0):

Your media query css rule might not be strong enough to override your original css rule. Make sure they both match the same rule, so that they match in terms of weight aswell.

You can also try to debug this by adding an !important to your media query css rule to see if it's really just an override issue.